# How can I get information about redirects in the Wayback Machine API?

Tags: api, archive.org

As some of you may have noticed across the network, I have a couple of scripts to repair [broken images](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) or [broken links](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5223/70594). They often make use of the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/), which has a simple [API](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php) to query the latest snapshot of a page.

I'm currently checking whether I can fix the [many broken links to `springerlink.com`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22springerlink.com%22). I've noticed that broken links like http://www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/, found in [this Skeptics.SE answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/928/26375), have been [saved in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2015*/http://www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/):

> ```
> Loading...
> http://www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/ |
> 02:35:13 January 12, 2015
> Got an HTTP 301 response at crawl time
> Redirecting to...
> http://link.springer.com/10.1023%2FA%3A1014576505223?from=SL
> ```

and this redirect is very helpful; I'd like to use the final URL (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1014576505223?from=SL) in the edit. However, there seems to be no way for me to get this URL, or even the 'snapshot' from the API. It seems the API only serves 'completely successful' snapshots. I've tried the following URLs:

- https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/
- https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=//www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/
- https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=http://www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/
- https://archive.org/wayback/available?url=https://www.springerlink.com/content/g29akrhnyf0ul4np/

but none of them work. Any ideas, or should I just try to mimic a browser request?